# Развёртывание сайта

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Написал проект на mvc. Создал под него пул, пытаюсь запустить его. Если ставлю в пуле версию asp.net 4.0 вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ставлю без управляемого кода, тогда вылетает уже другая ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее вылетала 502, но я в строке:

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="Views/*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

в части path добавил Views/. И теперь вот такая вот ошибка. И не как не получается запулить сайт. В чём проблема не пойму, не одну ошибку решить не получилось. Таргетная версия framework в проекте 4.6.1. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема. Если понадобиться ещё какая то информация для анализа проблемы пишите, я добавлю.

Comment: ткните там попробуйте Copy Local для указанной отсутствующей зависимости

Comment: @teran а поподробнее можно? Где это нажать? И кстати разобрался что вариант без упровляемого кода не подойдёт ибо это mvc и там куча razor вставок, так что нужно разбираться с ошибкой где не находит библиотеку. МОгу сказать ещё что попробовал открыть свойсва библиотеки которая лежит в bin и в ошибке прочитал что возникает при пуле приложения, там разные паблик кей токены, но почему не пойму

Comment: @teran можете что нибудь подсказать? Я попробовал даже создать пустой mvc проект, он же выводит пример страницы со ссылками на сайт microsoft. И попытался его запулить, тот же самый результат, ошибка на сборку Web.MVC